# what is the concept of store in OpenID

Tags: python, openid, store

Hi so this is what I understand how Openid works:-

1. the user enters his openid url on the site say"hii.com"
2. The app does a redirect to the openid provider and either does the login or denies it and sends the response back to the site i.e"hii.com"
3. If authentication was succesful then the response object provided by the openid provider can contain other data too like email etc if "hii.com" had requested for it.
4. I can save this data in the database.

Please correct me if I am wrong. However what I am not understanding here is the concept of stores. I see openid.store.filestore,nonce,sqlstore. Could someone please provide some clarity on it. What role does this store play here.
I have gone through python openid docs but end up feeling clueless.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upd.: my previous answer was wrong

The store you are referring to is where your app stores the data during auth.

Storing it in a shared memcached instance should be the best option (faster than db and reliable enough).