# Is it possible to use OpenID/oAuth as SSO for different platform on single domain?

Tags: java, php, openid, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

In my case, I have four platform.

2 Platforms are in PHP and 2 Platforms in JAVA on single domain.

Like

```
www.example.com/login.php (Main page to login in platform)
```

If user is login allow him to access any of this platform without login.

```
www.example.com/php1 
www.example.com/php2
www.example.com/java1
www.example.com/java2
```

What I want is to use common login for all platform. I can not share session in my case because both platform have different server(Apache, JBOSS)

Is is possible to use OpenID in this case ? If Yes How ?
One more thing  is possible use oAuth in this case ?

If none of above will not suitable in my case any other idea ?

Comment: Uh... why not use/write session handlers that use the same store?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How ? We have different server for both platform (Apache for php & JBOSS for JAVA). In this case how to share sessions ?

Answer (score 1):

The platform doesn't really matter if the authentication is done against the same store. So make all your applications authenticate using the same LDAP, database, service, etc...
See [what is the concept of store in OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937456/what-is-the-concept-of-store-in-openid)

---

Using OpenID is possible. 
Using OAuth is also possible.

Though it is possible to use OAuth for authentication, OAuth is more about authorization.
[From OAuth Wikipedia article's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)

> OAuth is a service that is complementary to, and therefore distinct
>   from, OpenID.

---

For how to use OpenID and/or OAuth in Java/PHP, check the documentation of OpenID and OAuth libraries such as:

- [openid4java](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/)
- [OpenID - Pear](http://pear.php.net/package/OpenID/redirected)

Also check the documentation of the service providers.